# jupyter notebookでCSVファイルを読み込めない

Tags: python3, csv, jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebookでCSVファイル読み込みたいのですが、csvデータをどこに保存すればいいかわかりません。どこに保存すればいいですか？

Comment: jupyterのセルの中でpwdコマンドを実行すると、編集中のnotebookのディレクトリが表示されます。その場所‌​にcsvファイルを置けばファイル名だけど‌​読めるはずです。

Answer (score 2):

例えばここのHP　http://pythonhow.com/data-analysis-with-python-pandas/　上に置いてある。[http://pythonhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Income.csvをダウンロードして](http://pythonhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Income.csv%E3%82%92%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6)、デスクトップに保存して、次のコマンドをjupyter notebookで打ち込むと

```py
import os
os.path.isfile('/Users/user/Desktop/Income.csv')
```

もし、Trueと出ればそこのディレクトリに保存されてあるので、次のコマンドを打ち込めば、

```py
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Income.csv')
print(df1)
```

次の結果が出てきませんか。お聞きしている読み込むと保存はこういう事でしょうか？

```py
GEOID;State;2005;2006;2007;2008;2009;2010;2011;2012;2013
0  04000US01;Alabama;37150;37952;42212;44476;3998...      
1  04000US02;Alaska;55891;56418;62993;63989;61604...      
2  04000US04;Arizona;45245;46657;47215;46914;4573...      
3  04000US05;Arkansas;36658;37057;40795;39586;365...      
4  04000US06;California;51755;55319;55734;57014;5...
```